# Running TOPCAT on Fedora

Tags: java, fedora

I downloaded the `topcat-full.jar` and the `topcat` files from the [TOPCAT website](http://www.star.bris.ac.uk/~mbt/topcat/#install), followed the instructions (`chmod +x topcat`) and tried to start topcat. But doing

```
./topcat
```

raises the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.AuxWindow.<init>(AuxWindow.java:95)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.ControlWindow.<init>(ControlWindow.java:244)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.ControlWindow.getInstance(ControlWindow.java:759)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.Driver.getControlWindow(Driver.java:556)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.Driver.runMain(Driver.java:448)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.Driver.main(Driver.java:185)
```

Doing

```
java -jar topcat-full.jar
```

also raises

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:189)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.AuxWindow.<init>(AuxWindow.java:95)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.ControlWindow.<init>(ControlWindow.java:244)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.ControlWindow.getInstance(ControlWindow.java:759)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.Driver.getControlWindow(Driver.java:556)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.Driver.runMain(Driver.java:448)
    at uk.ac.starlink.topcat.Driver.main(Driver.java:185)
```

I am using Fedora 30, and `java -version` says

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

How can I get TOPCAT to run?

---

I tried to install openjdk

```
yum install java-openjdk
```

but I still get the same error message when running `./topcat`

Comment: Do you have a DISPLAY variable (and what is it)?

Comment: @harrymc `echo $DISPLAY` says `:0`

Comment: @usernumber Please [edit] your post adding the java version in use (`java --version`). Check here [this answer from 2015](https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/issues/87). BTW add even the steps done: e.g. I downloaded `topcat-full.jar`, changed the attributes with `chmod u+x topcat-full.jar`, then executed with `./topcat-full.jar` and with `java -jar topcat-full.jar`. In my case, under ubuntu, both worked as expected. The used java (`type java` and search for the last linked one) is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`. You can try select a specific java if there are more than 1.

Comment: @Hastur `java --version` says `Unrecognized option: --version`

Comment: @usernumber It seems Ubuntu and RedHat number the java versions in a very different way. In case you may try to select a different installed version via `sudo alternatives --config java`. You can also try to see where the executed command is on the file system via `type java`, then `ls -l  the-answer-of-type-invocation` (`ls` more times if needed to follow more than one symbolic link). Just as a note on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with `openjdk 11.0.5 2019-10-15` works with no effort...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment by @Hastur, I did

```
sudo alternatives --config java
```

Then I selected `java-latest-openjdk.x86_64` from the list, and tried `./topcat` again, and it worked, but I have no idea why.

Comment: _I have no idea why_. Because of the dependencies of `topcat`: `java-latest-openjdk.x86_64` satisfied the needs of `topcat`, the other one not `:-) ` Feel you free to call me [La Palisse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_de_La_Palice) `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that Fedora defaults to a "headless" installation of Java.

I fixed this by installing the java-openjdk package.

https://openjdk.java.net

Comment: Thanks! But after installing java-openjdk, the error message is the same.